# Create graph of user logins

Tags: powerbi

I have data like this:

[image]

in Power BI.   As you can see, it's rows of when users of my system logged in.  Often one user will be several rows in a row, if they logged out and logged back in.   I'd love to create a graph that kinda shows how many people are logged in on any given day, POSSIBLY by hour, but at least by day.  Kinda thinking something like this:

[image]

(pardon my MS Paint skills)

Well, the columns are 'date/time' format like I'd expect, and when I put on a visual, I get this instead:

[image]

At the very least I'd love to chart when people logged in, but if possible I'd love to take into account their 'logout' time as well, to show volume of people currently logged in at any given time.

I'm sure I'm missing something obvious, (do I need to create a count or something first?)  But would appreciate any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Date and Time Dimension Table.
[image]

Once you have this table, Make sure it fits the Power BI requirements, for DirectQuery it has to be less than 1 Million Rows, and for Import less than 10 GB, etc. Read up from this [link](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Number-of-records-limitation/td-p/9552).

Now after you've figured out your Date/Time Dimension table, you will need to join your Login Time and Logout time to this table. Create a Key similar to how I did in the Image for Login and LogOut time and join it to the Date Dimension table key.

Better to do this in SQL, when Login Matches, assign 1, when logout matches assign 0 and name it as Switch. then use the date from the date dimension as the x-axis and Switch as the Y-axis. you will get your sine wave graph for login and log-out information. Good to track users who forget to clock out.

For Hours worked the logic is similar, but the calculation is different in the final step.

Comment: Thank you!  Worked great!  Followed this https://radacad.com/how-to-use-time-and-date-dimensions-in-a-power-bi-model  to get the time and date dimension table and my graph looks great now.  I still haven't got the 'time' part working, but the dates are working as intended.